# Using enums from prisma in nestJS graphQL models

Tags: enums, graphql, nestjs, prisma

My object that is supposed to be returned:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => String)
  email: string

  @Field(() => [Level])
  level: Level[]
}
```

Level is an enum generated by prisma, defined in schema.prisma:

```
enum Level {
  EASY
  MEDIUM
  HARD
}
```

Now I'm trying to return this User object in my GraphQL Mutation:

```js
@Mutation(() => User, { name: 'some-endpoint' })
```

When running this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "Level". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can't enums from prisma be used as a field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you can.

```
import { Level } from '@prisma/client'

@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => String)
  email: string

  @Field(() => Level)
  level: Level
}

registerEnumType(Level, {
  name: 'Level',
});
```

You should use `registerEnumType` + `@Field(() => Enum)`

https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/unions-and-enums#enums

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the registration of the enum type in GraphQL:

```
// user.model.ts
registerEnumType(Level, { name: "Level" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put it key-value and it worked with prisma.

```
enum Role {
  USER = 'USER',
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
}

registerEnumType(Role, {
  name: 'Role',
});

export class CreateUserInput {
@IsEnum(Role)
@Field(() => Role, { nullable: true })
role?: Role;
}
```

and do it like this in the service:

```
async create(createUserInput: CreateUserInput): Promise<User> {
    return this.prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        ...createUserInput,
      },
    });
  }
```

and It worked.Hope it help